# "Error: package or namespace load failed for 'CIMLR' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)" in installing R package CIMLR

Tags: r, r-package

I kept getting error when installing CIMLR in R4.3.1 in Windows. I would be very grateful if you could give me some favor about this.

Below is the error information:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("danro9685/CIMLR", ref = 'R')
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_TOKEN
Downloading GitHub repo danro9685/CIMLR@R
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔ checking for file 'C:\\Users\\59307\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp00R5rk\\remotesb9406dcb539c\\danro9685-CIMLR-d14531e/DESCRIPTION' (1.1s)
─ preparing 'CIMLR':
✔ checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─ cleaning src
─ checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─ checking for empty or unneeded directories
─ building 'CIMLR_1.0.0.tar.gz'
...
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'CIMLR' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'D:/R-4.3.1/library/00LOCK-CIMLR/00new/CIMLR/libs/x64/CIMLR.dll':

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed

removing 'D:/R-4.3.1/library/CIMLR'
```

Anyone have a solution?
Thanks in advance.